# asynctask doInBackgound() not running if there's a asynctask already running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When the user logs in into my app. I am starting an `asynctask` to maintain the user session. And that async task is running indefinitely till the user logs out. My problem is that when I try to start other `asynctasks`, their `doInBackground()` method is never executed.

I read somewhere that if an async task is already running, we cannot start new `async task`. I can confirm this because when i removed the user session async task, it worked properly. Is there a workaround?

P.S.: I have already used `executeOnExecutor()` method. but it didn't help.

Comment: Rather than work around it I would recommend using the asyncTask properly for its designed purpose of executing a long running operation on a background thread and find another solution for maintaining your user session.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible

Comment: @Kuffs Can you suggest me another solution to maintain the user session.

Comment: Depends on what that actually means to you. If you simply want to keep a variable set for the life of the application, you could extend your application class and store it in there. e.g http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/

Comment: My user session means that it checks every 15 min if the app is in background and if it is, it should restart the app rather than resuming the app from same screen.

Comment: For this, you could store the current time in your extended app class whenever an activity closes and clear it whenever an activity opens. If the stored value is more than 15 minutes ago when the activity starts, restart the app. This also has the advantage of not running an unnecessary process continually on the device. If your API levels allows, you can use registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks for this. Otherwise extending a base activity would make this easier to handle.

Comment: But If application is already in background, how will i check this. The beauty of asynctask is that it will continue to run and check.

Answer (score 6):

For potentially long running operations I suggest you to use `Service` rather than `asynctask`.

Start the service when the user logs in

```
Intent i= new Intent(context, YourService.class);
i.putExtra("KEY1", "Value to be used by the service");
context.startService(i);
```

And stop the service when the user logs out

```
stopService(new Intent(this,YourService.class));
```

To get to know more about `Service` you can refer this

[Service : Android developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

[Service : Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

To know more about `asynctask` vs `service` you can refer this

[Android: AsyncTask vs Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957775/android-asynctask-vs-service)

[When to use a Service or AsyncTask or Handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285680/i-dont-know-when-to-use-a-service-or-asynctask-or-handler)

Answer (score 4):

**I read somewhere that if an async task is already running, we cannot start new async task.**

> Yes,That is fact that you can't run more then 5 (five) `AsyncTask`at same time below the API 11 but for more yes you can using [executeOnExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29).
>
> AsyncTask uses a thread pool pattern for running the stuff from `doInBackground()`. The issue is initially (in early Android OS versions) the pool size was just 1, meaning no parallel computations for a bunch of AsyncTasks. But later they fixed that and now the size is 5, so at most 5 AsyncTasks can run simultaneously.

I have figure out  [Some Threading rules](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and i found one major rule is below ,

```
The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)
```

**What is definition of `AsyncTask`?**

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

**How & Where use it?**

AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended to use it.

**Why you can't use multiple `AsyncTask` at same time ?**

There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class to work properly:

- The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the **UI thread**. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
- The ***task instance*** must be created on the UI thread.
- `execute(Params...)` must be invoked on the UI thread.
- Do not call `onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` manually.
- The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)
- [Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time — not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)
- [Test sample of parallel excution of AsyncTasks](https://github.com/vitkhudenko/test_asynctask)

**Try Executor**

You should go with [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) that will mange your multiple thread parallel.

```
Executor executor = anExecutor;
executor.execute(new RunnableTask1());
executor.execute(new RunnableTask2());
...
```

- [Sample Example 1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/AsimpleexamplethatusesanExecutor.htm)
- [Sample Example 2](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html)

Answer (score 3):

Just like a few others here, I object to the premise of the question.

Your core problem is that you are using an `AsyncTask` to perform a task beyond its scope. Others have noted this too. Those who offer solutions that can mitigate your problem through low-level threads (even `java.util.Concurrent` is low-level which is why Scala uses Akka actors as an abstraction), `Service`, *etc.* are quite clever, but they are treating the symptom rather than curing the disease.

As for what you *should* be doing, you are not the first to want to maintain a user session in an Android application. This is a solved problem. The common thread (no pun intended) in these solutions is the use of `SharedPreferences`. [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) is a straightforward example of doing this. [This Stack Overflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622375/android-storing-user-session-in-shared-preferences) combines `SharedPreferences` with OAuth to do something more sophisticated.

It is common in software development to solve problems by preventing them from happening in the first place. I think you can solve the problem of running simultaneous `AsyncTask`s by not running simultaneous `AsyncTask`s. User session management is simply not what an `AsyncTask` is for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing for API 11 or higher, you can use `AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()` allowing for multiple AsyncTasks to be run at once.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Params...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29)

Answer (score 2):

I'll share with you, what we do on our App.

To keep user Session (We use OAuth with access/refresh tokens), we create a **Singleton** in our **Application extended class**. Why we declare this Singleton inside the MainApplication class? (Thats the name of our class), because your **Singleton's life will be tided to the Activity that has created it**, so if your Application is running on low memory and Garbage Collector collects your paused Activities, it will release your Singleton instance because it's associated to that Activity.

Creating it inside your Application class will let it live inside your RAM as long as the user keeps using your app.

Then, to persists that session cross application uses, we save the credentials inside SharedPreferences encrypting the fields.

Answer (score 1):

yes starting 2 or more asynctasks simultaneously may cause issues on some devices. i had experienced this issue few months back. i could not predict when the 2nd asyncTask would fail to run. The issue was intermittent may caused by usage of memory as i was executing ndk code in asynctask. but i remember well that it depended on memory of device.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question had been asked before. I would post the link for the similar question.

[AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor() before API Level 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211684/asynctask-executeonexecutor-before-api-level-11)

Some users suggest go for `Service`. My advice is don't go for that path yet. Using service is much more complicated. Even you are using service, you still have to deal with threading, as

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is
>   going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such
>   as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to
>   do that work....

If we can solve a problem in elegant way, don't go for the complicated way.

**I would suggest that, try one of the APIs in `java.util.concurrent` as suggested in below**

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.

I can't give you any code example so far, as I do not know how you design your session managing mechanism.

If you think your long running session managing task shouldn't bind to the life cycle of your main application life cycle, then only you might want to consider `Service`. However, bear in mind that, communication among your main application and `Service` is much more cumbersome and complicated.

For more details, please refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html, under section **Should you use a service or a thread?**